# How can I make my Facebook profile completely private?

Tags: facebook, privacy

How can I make my Facebook profile completely private?

I don't want people to be able to see me.

Comment: That’s not possible. Your photo will be visible even if you set everything to be visible only by you.

Comment: How about a little clarification as to why you don't want anyone to see anything at all? If you want NO information public, why not just cancel Facebook? I mean, being seen is the definition of Facebook. To host your photos, if that is the reasoning in keeping Facebook, there are plenty of other services, like Picasa and Dropbox, to name a few.

Comment: @TravisPflanz Facebook is great as long as it works between friends and not strangers.

Comment: Asker has specified that this should be for "Friends" and not literal "completely private"

Comment: Facebook is a great source of news and I know a few people who use it just to get updates from companies, etc. without any interest for the social aspect of it. There’s plenty of reasons someone might not want any information “leaked” out of Facebook. In general I wish people would just stop answering questions with something along the lines of “you’re doing it wrong”.

Comment: @TravisPflanz If you want to start a commercial/company Facebook page, you MUST have a Facebook account. What if you don't want your personal Facebook account to be visible to others--you just want the professional presence of the page?

Comment: Even though this is a 3 year old question, I will reply. My thought behind this is that if you're the owner of a legitimate business, you shouldn't hide that fact. It is shady, if you ask me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your [privacy settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy) page and change everything to `Friends`. Each of the sections have areas that need to be changed:

- Default Privacy (within custom, then `Friends`)
- How you connect (click edit then select `Friends` for each of the three choices)
- Timeline and Tagging

  - Click Edit then select `Friends` for each of the three choices with drop downs
  - Turn on "Review posts friends tag you in before they appear on your timeline
  - Turn on "Review tags friends add to your own posts on Facebook"
  - Click "Who sees tag suggestions when photos that look like you are uploaded" and select `Friends`
- Ads, Apps, and Websites

  - Turn them all to `Friends` within each of the settings or remove apps that you don't want to use
  - In the "How people bring your info to apps they use" area uncheck everything
- Limit the audience for past posts

  - Click "Limit Old Posts"
  - Set to `Friends`

Comment: if I set it as "Only me", than my friends won't be able to see it anymore as well. This is not what I want...

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question. You said "Completely Private". If you want only your friends then where I say `only me` change it to `Friends`.

Comment: I'll update my answer for this new information

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Privacy Settings -> Ads -> Apps -> Websites -> Edit Settings`. Scroll down to *"Public Search"* and disable it.

No one will be able to see that you even have a Facebook page unless they are your friends.

Answer (score 2):

> Your name, gender, username, and user ID (account number), along with your **profile picture, cover photo**, and networks (if you choose to add these) are available to anyone. This is because this information is essential to helping you connect with your friends and family.

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=167709519956542).

So anybody can see those details—your friends, friends of your friends and pretty much anybody who has the direct link to your account. And if you didn’t turned off the public search feature, anybody who finds your profile by searching you on a search engine (e.g. Google).