# How can I make only my name, profile picture and cover photo publicly visible on my Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook

How can I make my Facebook Profile private, to where people that aren't my friends can only see my Profile Pic and Cover Pic along with obviously my name. Actually I'm mostly worried about making my pictures private, I would like to have it set up to where people that aren't my friends can't go through my old profile pictures

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26538/29140

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to check each of your photo albums' / photos  sharing settings. Even though you probably set your privacy settings to be "ONLY FRIENDS" there have been instances that whenever you create albums /upload new photo its made public by default. I personally observed this while browsing around FB. All along I thought all my photos are friend only, apparently they're not.